# pandas multi-column merge on index

Tags: pandas, merge

hello i'm newbie in pandas

for example, datas of cryptocurrency are as below

**BTC**

```
time(index) open high low close value
0           1     4    1    2     1
1           2     5    2    3     2
```

**ETH**

```
time(index) open high low close value
1           1     1    1    1     1
```

and I want merge these datas as blow

**BTC X ETH**

```
                      BTC                        ETH
time(index) open high low close value  open high low close value
0           1     4    1    2     1    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1           2     5    2    3     2     1    1    1    1     1
```

is there any way to merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` for first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=('BTC','ETH'), axis=1)
print (df)
             BTC                       ETH                      
            open high low close value open high  low close value
time(index)                                                     
0              1    4   1     2     1  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
1              2    5   2     3     2  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0   1.0
```